# Не отображается картинка (путь относительный) на локальном сервере

Tags: javascript, img, localhost

Есть картинка img src="../../images/1.jpg" alt="lol"></img. Сто раз проверил, относительный путь соответствует структуре папок. При старте локального сервера на компьютере картинка не отображается, в инспекторе при наведении мыши путь отображается как http://localhost:3000/images/1.jpg

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пробовал результат тот же, может быть мне нужно что-то еще установить в проект, какой-нибудь npm пакет. На всякий случай скрин структуры.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй просто оставить один (../) вместо двух (../../)

Comment: import one from '../../imagaes/1.jpg'
...
<img src={one}/>

Comment: Да, спасибо, так работает.